# Big table - what to do about it?

Tags: tables

So I have quite a big table, as you will see in my code. I'd prefer (if possible) to have the table fit on a "normal" portrait page (personal preference as I think it is easier to read). Mainly the problem are the long headings (particularly for the last 3  columns), so perhaps wrapping text would be suitable. However if the table cannot be fitted onto a portrait page (and look reasonably pleasant!), I guess I'd have to go the horizontal page route. What would be the most suitable package to use and what would be the relevant code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Presentation of survival data for the whole sample (N = 13 298)}
\label{table:SurvivalAll}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
!{\extracolsep{\fill}}
l
*{8}{S[table-format=2.2]} 
}
\toprule
{\bfseries Year} & {\bfseries Risk Set} & {\bfseries Graduated} & {\bfseries Academically Excluded} & {\bfseries Transferred} & {\bfseries Censored} & {\bfseries Hazard Ratio - Graduates (\%)} & {\bfseries Hazard Ratio - Academically Excluded (\%)} & {\bfseries Hazard Ratio - Transferred (\%)} \\
\midrule
1 & 13 298 & 0 & 725 & 583 & 1915 & 0.00 & 5.45 & 4.38  \\
2 & 10 075 & 0 & 474 & 176 & 1617 & 0.00 & 4.70 & 1.75 \\
3 & 7 808 & 1266 &  334 &   38 &    1030 &  16.21 & 4.28 &  0.49 \\
4 & 5 139 & 2782 &  147 &   2 & 455 &   54.14 & 2.86 &  0.04 \\
5 & 1 754 & 1135 &  76 &    2 & 205&    64.71 & 4.33 &  0.11 \\
6 & 336 &   235 &   17 &    0 & 39 &    69.94 & 5.06 &  0.00 \\ 
7 & 45 &    28 &    7 & 0 & 5 & 62.22 & 15.56 & 0.00 \\
8 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 2   & 60.00 &   0.00 &  0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's [just too much content to fit in the page portrait-wise](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1v542.png). The linked image has `\tabcolsep` set to 50% of it's original width, and all the headings are stacked, as well as the entire table is set in `\small`. Yet the last two column still stretch entirely out into the margin. I think going with a side-ways table is probably the only option.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ClearOffTheTableMd.gif) if you haven't yet seen it. (in general, not too applicable here)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add a legend to the caption and abbreviate the headers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx,caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption[Presentation of survival data for the whole sample ($N = \num{13 298}$)]
  {Presentation of survival data for the whole sample ($N = \num{13 298}$). Legend:
  Y:~Year; RS:~Risk Set; G:~Graduated; AE:~Academically Excluded;
  T:~Transferred; C:~Censored; HRG:~Hazard Ratio --~Graduates;
  HRA: Hazard Ratio --~Academically Excluded; HRT:~Hazard Ratio --~Transferred}
\label{table:SurvivalAll}
\begin{tabular}{
 @{}
 S[table-format=1.0]
 S[table-format=5.0,group-four-digits=true]
 S[table-format=4.0]
 S[table-format=3.0]
 S[table-format=3.0]
 S[table-format=4.0]
 S[table-format=2.2]
 S[table-format=2.2]
 S[table-format=1.2]
 @{}
}
\toprule
{\bfseries Y} & {\bfseries RS} & {\bfseries G} &
  {\bfseries AE} & {\bfseries T} & {\bfseries C} &
  {\bfseries HRG} & {\bfseries HRAE} & {\bfseries HRT} \\
& & & & & & {(\%)} & {(\%)} & {(\%)} \\
\midrule
1 & 13 298 &    0 & 725 & 583 & 1915 &  0.00 &  5.45 & 4.38 \\
2 & 10 075 &    0 & 474 & 176 & 1617 &  0.00 &  4.70 & 1.75 \\
3 &  7 808 & 1266 & 334 &  38 & 1030 & 16.21 &  4.28 & 0.49 \\
4 &  5 139 & 2782 & 147 &   2 &  455 & 54.14 &  2.86 & 0.04 \\
5 &  1 754 & 1135 &  76 &   2 &  205 & 64.71 &  4.33 & 0.11 \\
6 &    336 &  235 &  17 &   0 &   39 & 69.94 &  5.06 & 0.00 \\ 
7 &     45 &   28 &   7 &   0 &    5 & 62.22 & 15.56 & 0.00 \\
8 &      5 &    3 &   0 &   0 &    2 & 60.00 &  0.00 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Code for both stretching the table and adding a vertical space before the legend. I'd not stretch the table, to be honest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx,caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption[Presentation of survival data for the whole sample ($N = \num{13 298}$)]
  {Presentation of survival data for the whole sample ($N = \num{13 298}$).\\[\medskipamount]
   Legend:
   Y:~Year; RS:~Risk Set; G:~Graduated; AE:~Academically Excluded;
   T:~Transferred; C:~Censored; HRG:~Hazard Ratio --~Graduates;
   HRA: Hazard Ratio --~Academically Excluded; HRT:~Hazard Ratio --~Transferred}
\label{table:SurvivalAll}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
 @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
 S[table-format=1.0]
 S[table-format=5.0,group-four-digits=true]
 S[table-format=4.0]
 S[table-format=3.0]
 S[table-format=3.0]
 S[table-format=4.0]
 S[table-format=2.2]
 S[table-format=2.2]
 S[table-format=1.2]
 @{}
}
\toprule
{\bfseries Y} & {\bfseries RS} & {\bfseries G} &
  {\bfseries AE} & {\bfseries T} & {\bfseries C} &
  {\bfseries HRG} & {\bfseries HRAE} & {\bfseries HRT} \\
& & & & & & {(\%)} & {(\%)} & {(\%)} \\
\midrule
1 & 13 298 &    0 & 725 & 583 & 1915 &  0.00 &  5.45 & 4.38 \\
2 & 10 075 &    0 & 474 & 176 & 1617 &  0.00 &  4.70 & 1.75 \\
3 &  7 808 & 1266 & 334 &  38 & 1030 & 16.21 &  4.28 & 0.49 \\
4 &  5 139 & 2782 & 147 &   2 &  455 & 54.14 &  2.86 & 0.04 \\
5 &  1 754 & 1135 &  76 &   2 &  205 & 64.71 &  4.33 & 0.11 \\
6 &    336 &  235 &  17 &   0 &   39 & 69.94 &  5.06 & 0.00 \\ 
7 &     45 &   28 &   7 &   0 &    5 & 62.22 & 15.56 & 0.00 \\
8 &      5 &    3 &   0 &   0 &    2 & 60.00 &  0.00 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg. A nice, 'innovative' solution. Just one question (and it's just a personal preference of mine), if I wanted my table to "stretch" the width of the page (taking into account my margins), where could I put the `\textwidth' command?

Comment: Also there is a way to create a bit more vertical space between the title of the table ("Presentation of survival data for the whole sample (N = 13 298") and the word "Legend"?

Comment: @Chris I wouldn't stretch the table beyond its natural length; for the vertical space, add ``\\[\medskipamount]`` before “Legend”. I'll add an example for both.

Comment: I actually agree with you. However I have about 9 tables currently and the others fill the width of the page. Is there an easy command I can insert for the other tables so they have a natural width? (Obviously they have different number of columns, some don't use siuntix etc.)

Answer (score 10):

perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Presentation of survival data for the whole sample (N = 13 298)}
\label{table:SurvivalAll}

\newcommand\hd[1]{\textbf{\parbox[t]{10mm}{\noindent\nobreak\hspace{0pt}\centering#1}}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
!{\extracolsep{\fill}}
l
*{8}{S[table-format=2.2]} 
}
\toprule
&&&&&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Hazard Ratio (\%)}}\\
\hd{Year} & \hd{Risk Set} & \hd{Graduated} & \hd{Excluded} &
 \hd{Transferred} & \hd{Censored} & 
\hd{Graduates}&
 \hd{Excluded}&
\hd{Transferred} \\
\midrule
1 & 13 298 & 0 & 725 & 583 & 1915 & 0.00 & 5.45 & 4.38  \\
2 & 10 075 & 0 & 474 & 176 & 1617 & 0.00 & 4.70 & 1.75 \\
3 & 7 808 & 1266 &  334 &   38 &    1030 &  16.21 & 4.28 &  0.49 \\
4 & 5 139 & 2782 &  147 &   2 & 455 &   54.14 & 2.86 &  0.04 \\
5 & 1 754 & 1135 &  76 &    2 & 205&    64.71 & 4.33 &  0.11 \\
6 & 336 &   235 &   17 &    0 & 39 &    69.94 & 5.06 &  0.00 \\ 
7 & 45 &    28 &    7 & 0 & 5 & 62.22 & 15.56 & 0.00 \\
8 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 2   & 60.00 &   0.00 &  0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\def\RB#1{\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Presentation of survival data for the whole sample (N = 13 298)}
\label{table:SurvivalAll}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
           S[table-format=5.0]
           S[table-format=4.0]
           S[table-format=3.0]
           S[table-format=3.0]
           S[table-format=4.0]
           S[table-format=2.2]
           S[table-format=2.2]
           S[table-format=1.2] } \toprule
{\RB{Year}} & 
  {\RB{Risk Set}} & 
  {\RB{Graduated}}  & 
  {\RB{\shortstack{Academically\\Excluded}}} & 
  {\RB{Transferred}} & 
  {\RB{Censored}} & 
  {\RB{\shortstack{Hazard Ratio -\\Graduates}}} & 
  {\RB{\shortstack{Hazard Ratio -\\Academically\\ Excluded}}} & 
  {\RB{\shortstack{Hazard Ratio -\\Transferred}}} \\\midrule
1 & 13 298 & 0 & 725 & 583 & 1915 & 0.00 & 5.45 & 4.38  \\
2 & 10 075 & 0 & 474 & 176 & 1617 & 0.00 & 4.70 & 1.75 \\
3 & 7 808 & 1266 &  334 &   38 &    1030 &  16.21 & 4.28 &  0.49 \\
4 & 5 139 & 2782 &  147 &   2 & 455 &   54.14 & 2.86 &  0.04 \\
5 & 1 754 & 1135 &  76 &    2 & 205&    64.71 & 4.33 &  0.11 \\
6 & 336 &   235 &   17 &    0 & 39 &    69.94 & 5.06 &  0.00 \\ 
7 & 45 &    28 &    7 & 0 & 5 & 62.22 & 15.56 & 0.00 \\
8 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 2   & 60.00 &   0.00 &  0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]